# Lotus Notes ODBC not found on Windows 10

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

User want me to update Lotus Notes data through an excel file. One way for me to do this is to import the excel data read through it then do an update. Unfortunately my machine (Windows 10) has no ODBC of Lotus Notes(8.5 ver) therefore I cant connect to the DB and do some update queries. Tried to search in google but I cant find any LN ODBC installer. Does windows 10 still support this ver. of Lotus Notes? Also, is there any other way that I can update the LN Data through imported excel data?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The Notes ODBC driver has always been an extra installer that has to be downloaded from IBM. You need credentials and a passport advantage contract or something similar to be allowed to download the driver. But there are a lot better ways to update Notes Databases from an excel file: use COM or OLE classes to directly write to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response Torsten. Actually I can already import excel data and then write it on Lotus Notes Database. What I'm lacking is the update part. Kinda new on LN so dont know yet the other ways on doing update. What I have I mind is to make an update query the typical one. Use LN Driver then connect and update. Anway I still have to research the other ways to write. :) Thanks again

Comment: If your organization has a current support agreement for Notes, someone in the organization will have a passport advantage account (or whatever the equivalent is now that Notes has been transferred from IBM to HCL) and will be able to download the NotesSQL driver for you.